# Is values passed to WooCommerce update_meta_data method fully sanitizing?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sql-injection, sanitization

I'm writing a WordPress plugin in which there is an input form for users with which they can add notes. I'm using WooCommerce `update_meta_data` method to save notes in database.

Considering this code:

```php
$note = isset($_POST['order_note']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['order_note']) : '';
$order->update_meta_data('_order_note', wp_json_encode($note));
$order->save_meta_data();
```

I know that `update_post_meta` sanitizes data (SQL Injection) before inserting it into database but how about `update_meta_data` ?

Is above code safe to use for inserting data in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `update_meta_data`

As far as I can see on the woo's [`update_meta_data`<sup>Source Code</sup>](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/74cd6f9be09cafd00fc0cbd00cb717e5f18bb8c1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-data.php#L425-L475), there is not any sanitizing function getting called.

#### `update_metadata`

On the other hand, if you take a look at the wordpress [`update_metadata`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_metadata/), there are two sanitizing functions getting called:

- [`sanitize_key`<sup>Source Code</sup>](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/ba943e113d3b31b121f77a2d30aebe14b047c69d/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L178)

and

- [`sanitize_meta`<sup>Source Code</sup>](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/ba943e113d3b31b121f77a2d30aebe14b047c69d/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L186)

---

So to answer your question, yes I would use a sanitizing function too before I update the meta data using `update_meta_data`.

In order to do that, `sanitize_text_field` would usually get the job done fine, but if you want to be sure that you're using the right sanitizing function, then use [`sanitize_meta`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_meta/) instead. That's what wordpress itself is using. Security-wise, I, personally, never had any problems using `sanitize_text_field` nor did I see anybody else having any problems with it. The snippet you provided us with, looks safe to me.