# Update custom meta data for Orders in Woocommerce

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to update the Woocommerce Orders with a custom meta data field

On Woocommerce order complete (status change) I have a Invoicing plugin that automatically generates customer invoice documents, this plugin has its own hooks/filters such as:

```
      apply_filters('moloni_after_insert_document', $this);

After it inserts (generates) the invoice, I use their API to return a value ( the invoice code ) that I want to save on that order meta data.

This is the code that I use:


add_action('moloni_after_insert_document', 'save_codigo_at', 10, 4 );
function save_codigo_at( $order_id ) {
    
    
    // On Order complete > access Moloni API > GETPDFLINK > Sanitize string and get Hash > Get document ID from order > 
    // Retrieve from the Database table moloni_api the access token from column main_token
    global $wpdb;
$table_name = "wp_moloni_api";
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = 1" );
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {
    $maintoken = $retrieved_data->main_token; 
     }
    
// Get document ID from the order
$documentid = get_post_meta($order->id, '_moloni_sent', true);

    
    // Connect to moloni API and getpdflink
    $url = "https://api.moloni.pt/v1/documents/getOne/?access_token=$maintoken";

    
    $postData = array(
   'company_id' => '11111',
   'document_id' => $documentid );
    
    
    $arguments = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
         'headers'  => array(
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ),
        'body' => $postData,
    );

    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $arguments );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        return "Something went wrong: $error_message";
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
        echo '</pre>';
        
        // jsondecode the string received by the API to remove weird backslashes, get and parse the URL and extract the HASH key
        $response2 = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
parse_str(parse_url(json_decode($response2, true)['url'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $result);
$hash = $result['h'];

//CONVERT JSON array to PHP array
$response3 = json_decode($response2);
        
$invoicecode = $response3->transport_code; //GET INVOICE CODE from the PHP ARRAY
    echo $invoicecode;

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        
$order->update_meta_data( '_codigo_at', $invoicecode );
        $order->save();
    
}
```

}

Now I am successfully able to get the code from their response.
However I can't save it because I always get the following PHP fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function update_meta_data() on bool in
```

From what I understood so far, this would likely be because $order is not defined as an object on this filter *moloni_after_insert_document*
Because when I try just to save a test random meta value but instead using a filter like *woocommerce_order_status_completed* then $order seems to work for updating meta data, the problem is that I must only run this action after the *moloni_after_insert_document* filter, because it is only then that the Invoice Code is generated and available

How could I properly define the $order inside of this code?
I am not sure how to handle/proceed in this situation

Thank you in advance for the attention and advice

Comment: if you look the documentation **update_metadata** accept object_id which i assume is $order_id in your case. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_metadata/ This could help you understand too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378332/is-values-passed-to-woocommerce-update-meta-data-method-fully-sanitizing

Comment: The error message basically means, that `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` returned false.

Comment: `$documentid = get_post_meta($order->id, '_moloni_sent', true);` - you do not even have an `$order` variable at that point.

Comment: @CBroe Yes just like I said in the above question, this specific filter is not passing $order as a variable, so I was asking for help in how to achieve this. I managed to figure it out by adding global $woocommerce, $post; to the code

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add

```
global $woocommerce, $post;
```

to the code, as adding this global has fixed the problem because it allowed to define the $order object.
I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing so, but it has managed to make the code work.